# why isnt temprorary ojbect constructor called?

Tags: c++

please check out the code below :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A{
    A(char* str) { cout << "default called" << endl; }
    A(const A &a) { cout << "copy called" << endl; }
};
int main() {
    A obj  = "str";
}
```

the Output is :

```
default called
```

why when i initialize object ,the consturctor of temprorary object isnt called ??
doesnt

```
A obj  = "str";
```

turn into

```
A obj = A("str") // so why consturctor of temprorary object isnt called ??
```

???

i know about Copy elision little bit that why copy constructor of `obj` isnt called
but why cosntructor of temprorary ojbect isnt called ??

Thanks!

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: This is an optimization.  The compiler can skip making a temporary and copying and instead directly construct the object in the destination

Comment: @NathanOliver Is it though? [It seems](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) it should always invoke the constructor directly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not seeing on that page where it disagrees with what I said.  The third bullet point covers this case and it has in it *The last step is usually optimized out and the result of the conversion is constructed directly in the memory allocated for the target object*

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, I stand corrected. Didn't read it properly.

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you mean, instead of doing it in two steps(1- call constructor for temporary 2- copy constructor for obj)
,The compiler for optimization does char* direct initialize and this is done in one step ??
Is what I said absolutely true?? and does the compiler actually work like that?

Comment: Yes.  Basically,, `A obj  = "str";` becomes `A obj("str");`, and this is allowed by the standard via the quote in the second answer on the dupe target.  even if the copy constructor has side affects, the standard allows the compiler to ignore them and directly construct the object.  This is a performance win with basically no down side.

Comment: @NathanOliver i got it ,thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

When you create an object by assignment C++ treats it as a constructor call.